# Ajax call to download pdf file in jsp

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, pdf, itext

I've tried to open itext created  pdf file using jsp code but not opening valid pdf file.

**BTW if I'll open pdf in generated path then it is valid generated pdf.**

```
<%

    //code to generate pdf on file location.

    String pdfurl = filePDF.getAbsolutePath();
    File pdf = null;

    try {

        System.out.println("pdfurl : " + pdfurl);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        pdf = new File(pdfurl);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=checklist.pdf");
        response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        response.setContentLength((int) pdf.length());

        OutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pdf);
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);

        int readBytes = 0;
        while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1) {
            sos.write(readBytes);
        }
        System.out.println("Finished writing bytes to output stream.");

        sos.flush();
        sos.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != pdf && pdf.exists() && !pdf.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                pdf.delete();
                System.out.println("Deleted file from " + pdfurl + " successfully");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error while deleting pdf from : " + pdfurl);
            }
        }
    }
%>
```

And angularJS code for ajax call:

```
pfqa.createDocument = function(action,data){
    $("body").addClass("loading");
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var paramJsonObj= {
        'userId' : userId,
    };

    var data = angular.copy(paramJsonObj);
    data = angular.toJson(data);

    $http({
     url : 'services/downloadPDF.jsp',
        dataType: 'json',
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json',
        },
        data: {data: paramJsonObj},
        responseType : 'arraybuffer'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var file = new Blob([ data ], {
            type : 'application/json'
        });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        var a         = document.createElement('a');
        a.href        = fileURL; 
        a.target      = '_blank';
        a.download    = 'checklist.pdf';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
}
```

Please guide me what I'm missing here.

Comment: Something may output some _garbage_ before writing the PDF in the output stream. Search for new lines before the '<%' tag or something like that.

Comment: The root of all evil here is to use JSP to generate binary format. Put your code into a servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is :

Use : **application/pdf** instead of **application/json**

```
$http({
 url : 'services/downloadPDF.jsp',
    dataType: 'json',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-type' : 'application/pdf',
    },
    data: {data: paramJsonObj},
    responseType : 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var file = new Blob([ data ], {
        type : 'application/pdf'
    });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    var a         = document.createElement('a');
    a.href        = fileURL; 
    a.target      = '_blank';
    a.download    = 'checklist.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}).error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**That's it !!!**